# Congruence Equation Partial Solutions

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to evaluate $x^2 = a\, mod\, n$ for large modulus. But I need only the first few solutions. How can I get it?

I tried following

```
Reduce[x^2 == 7946761, x, Modulus -> 130356633908760178920]
```

I got this output :

> ReplaceAll::reps:
>   {`ToRules[SystemException[RootsListSizeExceeded,100000]]}` is neither a
>   list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be
>   used for replacing. >>
>
> ReplaceAll::reps:
>   `{x==ToRules[SystemException[RootsListSizeExceeded,100000]]}` is neither
>   a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot
>   be used for replacing. >>

I also tried this

```
PowerModList[7946761, 1/2, 130356633908760178920]
```

with the output:

```
SystemException["PowerModListSizeExceeded", 1048576]
```

I don't need the complete set of solutions. Just first 10-15 are sufficient. How can I access them? Help please.

Answer (score 6):

Using v10.4.1, `Reduce` returns 2^17=131072 solutions beginning with these 5.

```
With[{a = 7946761, m = 130356633908760178920},
      x /. {ToRules[Reduce[x^2 == a, x, Modulus -> m][[Range[5]]]]}]

(* {2819, 639260064875759, 2448281311653851, 3275200757643631, \
    3967030855412441} *)
```

Your modulus `m` is composite, with prime factorization containing the first 16 primes.

```
FactorInteger[130356633908760178920]
(* {{2, 3}, {3, 1}, {5, 1}, {7, 1}, {11, 1}, {13, 1}, {17, 1}, {19, 1}, 
    {23, 1}, {29, 1}, {31, 1}, {37, 1}, {41, 1}, {43, 1}, {47, 1}, {53, 1}} *)
```

The strategy is to use `ChineseRemainder[r,k]` for all moduli `k` equal to the prime powers in `m=130356633908760178920`.

Use `PowerModList[a,1/2,k]` to find the remainders `r` for each individual prime-power modulus `k`.

```
With[{a = 7946761, m = 130356633908760178920},
     Table[PowerModList[a, 1/2, k], {k, Apply[Power, FactorInteger[m], 1]}]]
```

The full solution.

```
CRTsolution[a_, m_] :=
   Block[{f = FactorInteger[m], k, r},
         k = Apply[Power, f, 1];
         r = Flatten[
                Outer[List, Apply[Sequence, Map[PowerModList[a, 1/2, #] &, k]]],
                Length[f] - 1];
         Map[ChineseRemainder[#, k] &, r]]
```

The answers from `CRTsolution` agree with `Reduce`. The hope is that, by breaking the modulus apart, `CRTsolution` will work with your version of *Mathematica*.

```
With[{a = 7946761, m = 130356633908760178920},
     Total[
        Sort[CRTsolution[a, m]] - (x /. {ToRules[Reduce[x^2==a, x, Modulus->m]]})]]
(* 0 *)
```